TypeError: 'module' object is not callable for langchain
I'm new to langchain & I'm using langchain-0.2.12 langchain-core-0.2.28 in my spyder 4.1.4.
While I'm writing from langchain.llms import  I'm not seeing OpenAI, instead I'm seeing openai. So my import statement is from langchain.llms import openai. But while I'm running llm=openai(openai_api_key=api_key), I'm getting error message TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

I'd try from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI.My guess is openai is the module, OpenAI is the class in the openai module, and (either by design or accident) there's no __init__.py that imports OpenAI from openai in the llms module.
